# Build PJMEDIA (pjsip library) for Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, pjsip

I'm trying to build pjmedia for Android. 
From pjsip library (http://www.pjsip.org/).

I've followed official tutorial (https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android#OtherAndroidprojects)

1.Created config_site.h with next configuration:

```
define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1
include <pj/ config_site_sample.h>
```

2.Specified path to NDK

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path_to_android_ndk_dir
```

3.Run android configurations and do make

```
./configure-android
make dep && make clean && make
```

I've got builded **pjmedia** libraries in /pjmedia/lib directory

```
libpjmedia-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi.a
libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi.a
libpjmedia-codec-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi.a
libpjmedia-videodev-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi.a
libpjsdp-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi.a
```

**And questions:**

1. How should I use only pjmedia in Android app?
2. Where is JNI for pjmedia?
3. Should I create JNI .cpp wrapper by myself (with SWIG) and build it with pjmedia libraries into single library?
4. How to generate JNI with SWIG only for pjmedia?

I'm just little bit confused. They give me pjsua example with JNI and library but I don't want pjsua I need pjmedia! 
I just don't know how can I use it in Android.

OS: OS X Yosemite

NDK: v9d x86

Help me somebody please! :)
Thanks!